# Most suitable solution for storing time-series data in real time

Tags: mongodb, redis, time-series, influxdb

I want to store time-series data and access them in real time. My use case is storing them in real time, run a query to fetch data between 2 time frames (let's say fetch data of last 1 day or so). I need to do real time analytics to this data, so speed is important.

I am thinking to use something like Influx db, mongodb or Redis, but after reading about these databases, i am not sure which will be the fastest solution. 
Influx db is made for storing time-series data, Mongo db has time-series schema and pre-allocation technique, Redis is in-memory but also provides a persistence

Comment: PLease read [mcve]

Comment: Specific details for your use case would be necessary to make a reasonable recommendation. E.g., how much data are you working with? Just about anything would be workable for a few thousand data points, whereas thousands per second would require some care.

Comment: There is a module fro RedisLabs that may help you
https://redislabs.com/redis-best-practices/time-series/sorted-set-time-series/